# Facebook login with firebase in ios issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

//authenticate with firebase
Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
    if (error == nil) {
        self.fetchProfile(firebaseID: (authResult?.user.uid)!)
    }
}
```

I am getting this error. Please help me to resolve this issue. I have used this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login?authuser=1

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x604000846cf0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 403;
    errors = ({
         domain = global;
         message = "Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithIdp are blocked.";
         reason = forbidden;
    });
    message = "Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SignInWithIdp are blocked.";
    status = "PERMISSION_DENIED";
}}}}
```

Comment: Yes. i am able to login with facebook and getting credentials using access token also. But to auth with firebase getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1.
add pods as below

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

Step 2.
Add to your Info.plist file

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb<Your App id></string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string><Your App id></string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string><Your DisplayName></string>
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Step 3. 
Add to your AppDelegate

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Facebook
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    return handled
}
```

Step 4.
Add this to your View Controller

```
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginScreenViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btn_Facebook.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomFBLogin), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    ///FACEBOOK LOGIN
    func handleCustomFBLogin(sender:UIButton!){
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "public_profile"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if(err != nil){
                print("Custom FB Login Failed")
                return
            }
            //print(result?.token.tokenString)
            self.showEmailAddress()
        }
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!){
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully Logged in using facebook")
        showEmailAddress()
    }

    func showEmailAddress(){
        let accesstoken = FBSDKAccessToken.current();
    guard let accessTokenString = accesstoken?.tokenString else {return}

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, birthday, picture"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
            if(err != nil){
                print("Failed to start GraphRequest", err ?? "")
                return
            }
            print(result ?? "") 
        }

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){
        print("Logged out of Facebook")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because you are not configure signIn method of your firebase project. First configure signIn method in your project.

**To configure it follow below steps**
1 Open your firebase project in browser
2 Go to Authentication Section
3 Select Sign-In-Method
4 Enable your facebook login service
5 Save
6 Run Your Xcode Project

[image]

Comment: I already did this. for facebook i have added app id and secrete key. and took url and added in facebook settings

Comment: Follow this link

Comment: Then, make sure your OAuth redirect URI (e.g. my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your OAuth redirect URIs in your Facebook app's settings page on the Facebook for Developers site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185108/discussion-between-dnyaneshwar-wakchaure-and-rakesh-patel).